# Practical Applications of Radix Sort

Tags: algorithms, sorting, applied-theory, radix-sort

Radix sort is theoretically very fast when you know that the keys are in a certain limited range, say $n$ values in the range $[0\dots n^k -1]$ for example.  If $k<\lg n$ you just convert the values to base $n$ which takes $\Theta(n)$ time, do a base $n$ radix sort and then convert back to your original base for an overall $\Theta(nk)$ algorithm.

However, I've read that [in practice radix sort is typically much slower than doing for example a randomized quicksort](http://www.lamarca.org/anthony/caches.html):

> For large arrays, radix sort has the lowest instruction count, but
>   because of its relatively poor cache performance, its overall
>   performance is worse than the memory optimized versions of mergesort
>   and quicksort.

Is radix sort just a nice theoretical algorithm, or does it have common practical uses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Radix sorts are often, in practice, the fastest and most useful sorts on parallel machines.

- [Zagha and Blelloch: Radix sort for vector multiprocessors. *Supercomputing*, 1991: 712-721.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.51.7376)
- [Blelloch, Leiserson, Maggs, Plaxton, Smith, and Zagha: A Comparison of Sorting Algorithms for the Connection Machine CM-2. *Symp Parallel Algorithms and Arch* (SPAA-3):3-16, 1991.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.141.6584)
- [Arpaci-Dusseau, Arpaci-Dusseau, Culler, Hellerstein, and Patterson: High-performance sorting on networks of workstations. *Conf on Mgt of Data*, (SIGMOD-1997):243-254.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.141.2971)
- [Arpaci-Dusseau, Arpaci-Dusseau, Culler, Hellerstein, and Patterson. Searching for the sorting record: experiences in tuning NOW-Sort. *ACM Sigmetrics Symp Parallel and Distributed Tools*, (SPDT-2):124-133, 1998.](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Postscript/spdt98.pdf)

On each node of the multiprocessor you probably do something like a quicksort, but radix sort allows multiple nodes to work together with less synchronization than the various recursive sorts.

There are other situations too.  If you need a *stable sort* (a sort where whenever two keys are equal they stay in the same order rather than getting rearranged) then I'm not aware of any version of quicksort that will be of use.  Mergesort is also stable (if implemented correctly).  Your link is the first time I've ever heard anyone say that mergesort could be made to have better cache behavior than radix sort.

Comment: Patterson and Hennessy make the same point as the above linked paper by Lamarca in their book, Computer Organization and Design.

Comment: Your mention of Patterson reminded me of the important work that Andrea Arpaci-Dusseau did on sorting on clusters about 15 years ago.  (Patterson was a co-author).  In the 1997 paper they actually decided that partial-radix sort was preferable to quicksort on the individual nodes as well.  (I added the references to the answer).

Comment: That's interesting.  In the 2009 fourth edition of CompOrg they reference Lamarca's work on previous versions of Radix sort being cache unfriendly (pg. 489), but then on page 490 under graphs comparing Quicksort and Radix sort they say, "Due to such results, new versions of Radix sort have been invented that take memory hierarchy into account, to regain its algorithmic advantages."  I'm curious how these new versions of Radix Sort operate.

Comment: My suspicion is that Lamarca just used a stupid radix sort (one that keeps its buckets as linked lists.)  No-one would ever do that.  You would implement the buckets using some kind of optimized [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) (e.g., like a C++ `vector`).  But I don't know, as I haven't read Lamarca's papers.

Comment: @WanderingLogic where does radix sort use buckets? Do you mean bucket sort here?

Comment: @Bar, I was using the term _bucket_ in the same way it is used in the [Wikipedia article on radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), and in the papers I cited.  I apologize if that's not technically correct usage, these nuances of terminology are not something I'm good at.

Comment: @WanderingLogic Ah OK my mistake then.

Answer (score 4):

@Robert: Your link is quite surprising (actually I could not find the quoted sentence). My personal experience is for random input, radix sort is much faster than the STL `std::sort()`, which uses a variant of quicksort. I used to make an algorithm 50% faster by replacing `std::sort()` with an unstable radix sort. I am not sure what is the "memory optimized version" of quicksort, but I doubt it can be twice as fast as the STL version.

[This blog post](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/a-quick-note-on-radix-sort/) evaluated radix sort along with several other sorting algorithms. Briefly, in this evaluation, `std::sort()` takes 5.1 sec to sort 50 million integers, while in-place/unstable radix sort takes 2.0 sec. Stable radix sort should be even faster.

Radix sort is also widely used for stably sorting strings. Variants of radix sort are at times seen for constructing suffix arrays, BWT, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Radix sort is also a natural way to sort fixed-length words over a fixed alphabet, e.g. in Kärkkäinen & Sanders algorithm (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/realworld/papersS04/KaSa03.pdf)